# Meteor : add new fields on click event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a form which takes Username and contact details which includes phone number and type of contact(personal, office etc..), and I have a + button on whose click I want one more pair of contact details to be displayed.

So on each click of + button I want the user to enter more pairs of contact number and type.

Then when the user clicks on Submit button I want it to be saved.

Can anyone help me on how to accomplish this in Meteor

Comment: Question: Would you like to save the data as an array to the collection you are already editing like contact { name: , attr: , numbers: [{ type: , number: }, ...]} or should this been stored in a second linked collection? Do you have a schema?

Comment: I want to save in Mongodb so better is array right ?

Comment: This isn't depending on mongo - just take some thoughts on your design. If you want to re-use the data on some other focus it might be usefull to have them as a seperate collection, if not neccessary, then storing as an array is quite fine

Comment: array is fine for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

> Use **Jquery** for that append your dynamic input box in body or in
>   any div using **id** or **class**

And using **form** you can get value of all

```
 <form id="Dynamic">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="a"/>
    </div>
</form>
<button href="#" id="AddInpElem">Add Another Input Box</button>
<button href="#" id="s">submit</button>
```

```
var MaxInputs = 5;
var Dynamic = $('#Dynamic');
var i = $('#Dynamic div').size() + 1;

$('#AddInpElem').click( function () {
    if (i <= MaxInputs) {
        $('<div><input type="text" name="a'+i+'" /><a href="#" class="RemInpElem">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(Dynamic);
        i++;
    }
    return false;
});

$('#s').click( function () {
   var test = $('#Dynamic').serializeArray();
    console.log(test);
});

$("body").on("click",".RemInpElem", function(){
       if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
})
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/L9wtubnj/2/

Comment: .serializeArray(); will give you all data see above example

Comment: @Kevel thanks for your reply but I'm looking for something using {{#each}} {{each}} in Meteor

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [AutoForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) and [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema), which will do this for you once you define an array category.

```
MySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  myKey: {
    type: [String]  // this defines a string array
  }
});
```